# Global Secondary Index using attribute that not all items share?

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb

How is it possible that DynamoDB can create a global secondary index comprising of a partition key (and sort key) that not all items in the table share?
I'm not able to put an item into a table that doesn't have the proper primary key structure, so it doesn't make sense to me that I can create a GSI using an attribute as the partition key that not all items in the table have.

Let's say I have a table with 10 items. 5 items are users. 2 items are the products I sell. The 3 remaining items are orders that have been created.

Let's also say the attempt at approaching this NoSQL style was whole-hearted and half-understood, leaving us with these items and their corresponding attributes -

`user items: id, email, phone, address, first_name, last_name`

`product items: id, description, title, price`

`order items: id, user_id, product_id, quantity, creation_date`

The partition key of this table is `id`.

Then, when I try to create a GSI using `creation_date` as the partition key, it lets me... can someone explain why this works to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items that don't have `creation_date` attribute won't be included in the GSI. What matters is that all items that have `creation_date` do have `id`. The idea, in this case, of the GSI is so you can query your items/data by `creation_date` which otherwise you couldn't since that attribute is not a part of the partition key.

[Here is more on GSIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html)

in particular:

> If a table contains an item where a particular attribute is not defined, but that attribute is defined as an index partition key or sort key, DynamoDB doesn't write any data for that item to the index.